# How to get sub-domain of Wordpress in url structure

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, permalinks

I have created a Wordpress install on a sub-domain of my server. So for example my url is www.myUrl.com and I created a subdomain that is essentially `www.myUrl.com/sub`. I installed Wordpress on `www.myUrl.com/sub` and it works fine.

The site shows up on that new url as it should BUT when I click a link, lets say 'blog', instead of taking me to `www.myUrl.com/sub/blog` it takes me to `www.myUrl.com/blog`.

I am pretty new to wordpress and have looked up the issue but can't find any answers. I have messed with the absolute path stuff inside the .wp-config file but cant' figure out what to do and if this is indeed the file I need to change. I have also tried to find this on the permalinks page.

Please let me know what other information you need to help me answer this question and thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating the link 'blog'?  What is your WordPress siteurl is the general settings?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your home URL is defined as "www.myUrl.com" in the database. U can find this in the wp-options table in the database or in WordPress at the general settings. When I move to a subdomain I also delete the .htaccess and save the permalinks page of the settings so the .htaccess gets a refresh.